# How can I make the date and time the name of a screenshot taken by python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, screenshot, filenames

My program basically takes a screenshot when the key 'f2' is pressed and saves it in a directory, I am trying to get the screenshot to have the name of when the screenshot was taken, day and time so it won't overlap with any other pictures and make it unique.

This is the program:

```
import keyboard,pyautogui
from datetime import datetime

while True:
    try:
        
        if keyboard.is_pressed('f2'):
            myScreenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
            now = datetime.now()
            directory = r'E:\Recovery\boot\files\scr'
            print(str(directory) + "\\" + str(now))
            myScreenshot.save(str(directory) + "\\" + str(now))
            break
    except:
        break
```

Comment: pyautogui.screenshot(r'E:\Recovery\boot\files\scr'+ "\" + str(now)+".png") simply do this. You forgot the image type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the datetime `strftime` to provide a date\time format.

For file names, you should avoid colons and slashes in the date.

In your code, try this:

```
now = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S")  # 2020-08-23_211709
......
myScreenshot.save(str(directory) + "\\" + now + ".png")  # assuming png
```

As @arundeep mentioned in his comment, you can also save the capture directly:

```
pyautogui.screenshot(str(directory) + "\\" + now + ".png")
```